# Looping through a Pandas dataframe as a two dimensional array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

At some point in a running process i have two dataframes containing standard deviation values from various sampling distributions. 
dfbest keeps the smallest deviations as the best. dftmp records the current values..
so, the first time dftmp looks like this

```
       0         1          2         3         4
0  22.552408  7.299163  15.114379  5.214829  9.124144
```

with dftmp.shape (1, 5)

Ignoring for a moment the pythonic constructs and treating the dataframes as 2d arrays like a spreadsheet in VBA excel i write...

A:

```
if dfbest.empty:
    dfbest = dftmp
else:
    for R in range( dfbest.shape[0]):
       for C in range( dfbest.shape[1]):             
          if dfbest[R][C] > dftmp[R][C]:
             dfbest[R][C] = dftmp[R][C]
```

B:

```
if dfbest.empty:
    dfbest = dftmp
else:
    for R in range( dfbest.shape[0]):
       for C in range( dfbest.shape[1]):
          if dfbest[C][R] > dftmp[C][R]:
             dfbest[C][R] = dftmp[C][R]
```

Code A fails while B works. I 'd expect the opposite but i m new to python so who knows what i m not seeing here.. Any suggestions? I suspect there is a more appropriate .iloc solution to this.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input for `dfbest`?

Comment: why dont you put a breakpoint and see?

Comment: What are you asking exactally? Are you recieving an error message you don't understand? If so, post the error message in the question.

Comment: @Aryerez i am  asking why A fails and B succeeds

Comment: @AlexRamses the input for dfbest is shown on top

Comment: You had provided one numpy array but your code is using 2 numpy array. I can't test it without both.

Answer (score 1):

When you access a dataframe like that (`dfbest[x][y]`), `x` means a column, then `y` a row. That's why code B works.

Here is more information: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#basics

Comment: Yes luis.parravicini .. i suspect this is happening but not logical